# UISplitView's MasterViewController and Navigation Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

I am updating my existing app to include a SplitView for iPads.

I have it working with a UITabBar, but am having an issue with my masterViewController as it is generating a "duplicate" navigation bar that is covering my existing navigation items on all masterViewControllers (tabs), including searchBar on the search tab.

The code I have is:

AppDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{

    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    splitViewController.delegate = self
    splitViewController.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.33
    splitViewController.minimumPrimaryColumnWidth = 375
    splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible

    return true
}

func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController:UIViewController, onto primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

The reason for having this in the AppDelegate is I saw an example where placing it hear will allow me not to require the code in each of the different Master Views (each tab).  Have yet to test this as still working on the first master view.

Master View

```
override func viewDidLoad()

{

    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    // 3D Touch
    if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
        registerForPreviewing(with: self as UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate, sourceView: view)
        ThreeDTouch = true
    }

    self.addSwitchVewButtonToNavigationBar()
    self.addCategoryButtonToNavigationBar()

}

func addSwitchVewButtonToNavigationBar() {
    let switchButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)

    let editImage = UIImage(named: "CollectionButton")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    switchButton.setImage(editImage, for: .normal)
    switchButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SpeciesViewController.onSwitchView), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    let switchButtonFinal = UIBarButtonItem(customView:switchButton)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = switchButtonFinal

}

@IBAction func onSwitchView(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    AppDelegate.getAppState().isListViewSelected = false

    let speciesColletion = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Resource.SpeciesCollectionStoryboard) as! SpeciesCollectionViewController
    self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [speciesColletion]
}
```

Originally, the onSwitchViewButton was embedded using the IB, but did not work.  This is the same system used for the addFavorite on the Detail View.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that you addressing wrong UINavigation controller. I assume before splitting both master and SpeciesViewController existed in same navigation environment, and use same navigation controller. But in split view they don't. Your detail controller is actually UINavigation controller you are looking for, that had to control all navigation, and had to have buttons you need. You can get it from master as:

```
guard let split = splitViewController, let navController = split.viewControllers.last as? UINavigationController else { return }
```

And make sure that you split controller not embedded into another UINavigationController (reason for second navigation bar).

**EDIT:**
Function to return detail's Nav Controller:

```
var detailsNavigationController: UINavigationController? {
    return splitViewController?.viewControllers.last as? UINavigationController
}
```

[image: Storyboard]
[image: Split]
To access blue call detailsNavController, to access red use navigationController.

Comment: Thank you, Michael.  Correct.  I am modifying an existing app to incorporate splitView.  I am a self taught coder and all of my experience is with this one app, as a result, I have little to no experience with UINavigation.  Can you please please go into more detail on what code to use?

Comment: I gave you code that return  **details** view's navigation controller to use in **master** controller. You can create function to return optional value instead of guard, and use it in your code in places where you had to use **Detail's** nav controller

Comment: You can find useful to create new project using Master/Detail  template and compare storyboard and master view to yours. Please mind that template solutions are not perfect and you had to apply your brain to it first :)

Comment: Throwing an ounce of caution just to be sure we are on the same page.  The issue is the second navigationBar.  My BarButtonItems are displaying, just behind the second navigation bar, as you warned me.  My issue is removing the second navigation bar.  Are we are on the same page?

Comment: Original answer updated. I assume you have UINavigationController left to splitController. It will cause redundant nav bar to appear.

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  I am stumped as my splitView works, just not the navigation title of the MasterViewController.  It appears that maybe something deeper is causing this.  Can you give me advice what to search for in looking for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162803/discussion-between-michael-vorontsov-and-david-sanford).